# How to properly adapt the app UI on different screens on W10

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm about to start porting my WP8.1 app to W10, and looks like I'll have to make it a Universal Windows App. Now, I'm fine as for the back-end code, as I'll be able to reuse 90% of my classes (Models, ViewModels, and most of my helper classes, extension methods and converters).

The problem is for the UI: I understand I'll have to design the app for different screens and aspect rations, and I don't know how to actually implement that in code.
I mean, as for the UI scaling, I know I can use the VisualStateManager and AdaptiveTriggers to manually set the properties of the UI elements I want to adapt on any screen resolution, or I can use some converters, and that's fine.

Whan I mean is: what's the best method to have the whole UI adapt to different resolutions?

This is an example:

[image: People app on Windows 10]

As you can see: the whole navigation pattern changes along the UI when on different screens. On phones, we have the contact page that covers the whole UI, while on tablets and PCs we have the contact page that's just a fraction of the UI, and the pivot pages are moved into another panel on the right. Also, many of the UI elements are completely rearranged.
And of course, some view-level back-end code will change as well.

Now, I'm wondering what's the best approach to do this whole thing.

Should I:

• Have a single XAML file (for every page) with a lot of VisualStates and stuff, and try to rearrange the UI for every screen resolution

• Have different projects with a shared project (like with W8.1 universal apps), so that I can focus on the UI on every specific device? This is the approach I'd be more comfortable with, as I'd be able to design platform specific UI elements without problems. Still, I didn't understand how to actually create a shared project and different projects for each device type in VS2015.

• Use that approach with different XAML pages that share the same code-behind file (even I'm not sure how to implement this, and how to implement platform-specific code-behind parts).

• Some other method

I mean, I'm sure I'm not the only W8.1/WP8.1 developer in trouble here, is there some kind of advice I can use? I already watched all the MVA videos about W10 development, but they didn't get into the implementation details there.

Thank you for your help

Sergio

Comment: there are several triggers that you have to add: http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/using-adaptivetrigger-to-build-adaptive-uis-in-windows-10, https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10-Preview/09

Comment: I think it depends on what you're comfortable with.They don't differ much in terms of performance and there's no really best practice about it.I'm continuing my development in Universal style , which is shared code base and different XAML pages because this is what I'm comfortable with.I'd suggest the same thing because working on a single XAML page for different platforms / resolutions doesn't seem to be a good idea in terms of usability & readability for me.

Go for what you already know.

Comment: Totally agree. Separate projects are better especially when you got complex layout and many functionalities that differs between pc/phone.

Comment: Yeah, but I have two questions here: how do you create different linked projects on W10? And how can they generate a single output when compiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two screenshots aren't necessarily that different, if you look at using the [`SplitView` Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitview.aspx) and the [`RelativePanel` Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.relativepanel.aspx).

See [this //build talk](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-679) for more info.

Comment: Hello Peter, thanks for your answer. I saw the video, and the RelativePanel does look great. I still think I'd be more confortable with two separate views for phones and tablets/PCs, but I can think of many situations where this control would be useful. As for my navigation problem, I can see I had the wrong impression: they weren't actually using two separate frames, but just another SplitView control that was shown/collapsed using VisualStates :)

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on your project. If a UI isn't changing too drastically, I would definitely use AdaptiveTriggers. You can do a lot with very little XAML. Check out Microsoft's sample code if you haven't already: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/xaml_responsivetechniques

If it is changing drastically, you *can* do it with AdaptiveTriggers, but it's probably easier to have multiple XAML files. A new way to do this in Win10 is to use DeviceFamily. Essentially, just create a folder called "DeviceFamily-Mobile", and stick a XAML view with the same file name in there. More info: http://sharpgis.net/post/2015/04/01/Creating-DeviceFamily-specific-layouts-in-a-Universal-App

Comment: Yeah, the problem with this is that I couldn't use different controls in those pages, as the code-behind is always the same. That's why I thought about the multiple heads and the shared project, even though I haven't actually found how to do that in VS2015.
Also, I'd have to change the whole Navigation pattern, and to do that I'd be more comfortable working with different projects just like with W8.1/WP8.1 universal apps. Is it still possible to do that, even though the new universal apps have a single binary output file?